# Laravel 4 's all() method started to return Eloquent collection lately - why?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

This is my controller:

```
return View::make('home.listings')
    ->with('listings', Listing::all());
```

Previously, I checked it on views like this: (and it worked on all my projects)

```
@if(!empty($listings))
     //use foreach and show listings
@else
     <h3>No listing is found.</h3>
@endif
```

This is my Listing model.

```
class Listing extends Eloquent {

     public static $key = 'id';
     protected $table = 'ilanlar';
     public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Right now, it works when there is an entry in database. However, when there is not, it doesn't get to the else block. Because:

```
dd(!empty($listings)) //output: (boolean) true
```

And, when I output listings variable:

```
dd($listings) //outputs: 
    object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)[229]
            protected 'items' => 
                    array (size=0)
                            empty
```

This is the reason why it doesn't reach else block, because Eloquent returns and object and it casts to true.

**The problem is:** I don't know why it returns an Eloquent collection. Previously it didn't. Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Collection object has a [`isEmpty()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L415) method, so you could use that:

```
@if(! $listings->isEmpty())
    //use foreach and show listings
@else
    <h3>No listing is found.</h3>
@endif
```

Alternatively, you can convert everything to an Array:

```
return View::make('home.listings')
    ->with('listings', Listing::all()->toArray());
```

And use everything as an array within your views:

```
@if(!empty($listings))
    @foreach(listings as $listing):
    <li>{{ $listing['name'] }}</li>  <!-- Note $listing is treated as an array -->
    @endforeach
@else
    <h3>No listing is found.</h3>
@endif
```

Comment: Great response - thanks. Do you have any idea what causes the recent behaviour like this?

Comment: I actually thought that was *always* the behaviour, to be honest. I haven't come across this as an issue before myself.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue (if you'd call it an issue) the solution is to do `@if(count($listings))`

as you can see [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/79)

Comment: It previously worked fine. Is it because Laravel 4 updated Eloquent sources and this is the new usage, or just a small bug/issue waiting to be fixed?

Comment: @Aristona That i have no idea from what i see that issue was reported 10 months ago so it doesn't appear to be new. I can't say i've experienced it myself so i honestly don't know.

Comment: Strange. Just checked my old projects and I've never used count before - only empty. I'll temporarily solve my issue using count, but I really would like to know what exactly causes Eloquent to behave like this.

Comment: @Aristona I'm going to look into this also i think its odd that empty wouldn't work while count does..... i'll let you know if i find anything.

Comment: Have you by chance modified the `database.fetch` config setting?  I'm wondering if that would have anything to do with how Eloquent would handle empty data sets.