# Laravel5 Eloquent method All returning unexpected results

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to learn Laravel and I was really liking it until I got stumped!

I created a table called `suggestions` and seeded it with some fake data.

It looks like this:

[image]

I have a model file called `Suggestion.php` that has this code:

```
<?php
 namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class Suggestion extends Model
 {
 //
 }
```

In my `routes.php` file I have this:

```
use App\Suggestion;
Route::get('/', function () {
   $suggestions = Suggestion::all();
   return '<pre>' . var_dump($suggestions) . '</pre>';
});
```

**I'm expecting to get an array of the records** in my database, but instead I am getting a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` object that has two arrays, a `macros` array and an `items` array.  The beginning of the `var_dump` looks like this:

[image]

The data I want to access actually appears to be in `attributes` array, but it doesn't seem that this is how Laravel is supposed to work.

This really confuses me as I've been trying to follow a number of tutorials ([like this one](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)) and it seems that I should be getting a simple collection that I can loop over.

I did do some research on this issue and I did find other Stack Overflow posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814401/laravel-4-s-all-method-started-to-return-eloquent-collection-lately-why) but it doesn't really address my question.

I'm sort of figuring that I somehow messed up my Suggestions model or didn't do it correctly, but beyond that I'm lost.

Thanks, in advance, for any guidance you can give me. I actually intend to use a Controller and a View but for simplicity in presenting my problem here, I put the necessary code in the routes file.

Comment: You are supposed to receive a collection and iterate it. Please show us how you are iterating it at the moment.

Comment: As was said, just foreach over it as a normal array, collections are iterable. Models store their properties in the `protected $attributes` array. These properties are accessed by magic getters and setters.

TLDR: It's working correctly.

Comment: And if you *really* want to get an array you can call the `all()` method on the Collection,

Comment: Thanks to everyone for all of the comments and explanation!  I got it to work and using foreach works just fine.  I was thinking about this all wrong.  It turns out Laravel is easier than I ever expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Eloquent methods like all and get which retrieve multiple results, an
>   instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection will be returned.
>   The Collection class provides a variety of helpful methods for working
>   with your Eloquent results. Of course, you may simply loop over this
>   collection like an array

[from the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#retrieving-multiple-models)

so you are right eloquent return a collection.

it have a section in the documents how to work with it https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections

Comment: To add to this answer, if you want an array, use the Collection method `toArray()`

Comment: Thank you!  My question now seems rather dumb but I will leave it in case someone else thinks that they have the same issue.